# How do you properly input "$data" from one mySQL query into another query?

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to extract some data from my data table and input that data into another query. I believe my syntax is incorrect, as I am receiving no transfer of data. When my $data2->destination is echoed, the result is correct.

```
$query2 = 'SELECT * FROM booking WHERE status=1 AND userid= '.$user_ID.'';
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
$data2 = mysql_fetch_object($result2);
echo $data2->destination;


$query3 = 'UPDATE booking SET source=$data2->destination WHERE status=0 AND 
userid='.$user_ID.'';
$result3 = mysql_query($query3);
```

Comment: change $query3 = 'UPDATE booking SET source='.$data2->destination .'WHERE status=0 AND 
userid='.$user_ID.;

Comment: Beware sql injection

Comment: @ste-fu I plan on changing to mysqli after I figure this issue out.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query3 = 'UPDATE booking SET source=$data2->destination WHERE status=0 AND userid='.$user_ID.'';
```

should (could) be

```
$query3 = sprintf(
    "UPDATE booking SET source = %s WHERE status = 0 AND userid = %s",
    $data2->destination, 
    $user_ID
);
```

or

```
$query3 = "UPDATE booking SET source = $data2->destination WHERE status = 0 AND userd = $user_ID";
```

or

```
$query3 = 'UPDATE booking SET source = '.$data2->destination.' WHERE status = 0 AND userid = '.$user_ID;
```

Comment: @jameson1128: What do you get as `$query3` (dump it)

Comment: I get a bool(false) when I var_dump($result3)

Comment: @jameson1128: `var_dump($result3, true)`

Comment: When I throw an arbitrary value into the place of "$data2->destination", it works just fine. So I know it must be the syntax of that segment

Comment: @jameson1128: so, maybe, `$data2` isn't what you expect. please try to dump it and verify

Comment: Gives me "bool(false) bool(true)" as the result

Comment: var_dump($data2) is giving me all the correct info. It gives me an array of the correct row

Comment: @jameson1128: an array or an object? if is it an array, you should use that way: `$data2['destination'];`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105227/discussion-between-jameson1128-and-doncallisto).

Answer (score 0):

Variables inside strings are not getting evaluated if they are single quoted, use double quotes instead:
 [Double Quoted strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)